# deleting brackets in a file using sed

Tags: bash, scripting, sed

Can anyone help me in deleting brackets in a file ?
here is my script ..

```
  #!/bin/bash

for file in fftw is_c mpi_tile pmb tau xhpl
do
    for state in C0 C1 C2 C4
    do
    printf "${file}_${state}_v1.xls"

    sed -e 's/\(//' ${file}_${state}_v1.xls
    sed -e 's/\)//' ${file}_${state}_v1.xls

    awk '{sum+=$3} ; END {print "  ", sum/NR}' ${file}_${state}_v1.xls >> c-state-residency.xls
    done
done
```

Comment: sample input and sample output would be mucho beneficial

Comment: Not to mention the error you were getting.  I presume: `... Unmatched ( or \(`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution for deleting special characters

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in fftw is_c mpi_tile pmb tau xhpl
do
    for state in C0 C1 C2 C4
    do
    printf "${file}_${state}_v1.xls"
    sed -e 's/[()]//g' ${file}_${state}_v1.xls
    awk '{sum+=$3} ; END {print "Average C-state residency  ", sum/NR}' ${file}_${state}_v1.xls >> c-state-residency.xls
    done
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: use `--in-place` with sed to do what you think you're doing.

You're deleting parenthesis, not brackets, and only the first one on each line (or you would be if you removed the `\` you don't need).  This also seems like an odd thing to do to an Excel spreadsheet.

You probably want to pipe the output of the sed commands to awk instead of modifying the files in place though...

Answer (score 1):

I would use `tr -d ...`, like so:

```
$ echo "(this is my string)" | tr -d '()' 
this is my string
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using sed, it seems simpler to just use "tr" to replace the characters with nothing

```
 cat ${file}_${state}_v1.xls | tr '(' '' | tr ')' '' > ${file}_${state}_v1.xls
```